# How can I connect to my Mysql database with a DataBaseHelper class?

Tags: java

Recently I wanted to make a program that uses a mysql database and i can't figure out how to create the connection. Even if my program starts it doesn't load the my data.

```
package com.example.vet;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBConnection {
    private Connection conn;
    private static String DRIVER = "mysql";
    private static String HOST = "localhost";
    private static String PORT = "3000";
    private static String DBNAME = "dogs";
    private static String USER = "root";
    private static String PASS = "Admin";

    public DBConnection() throws SQLException {
        String url = String.format("jdbc:%s://%s:%s/%s", DRIVER, HOST, PORT, DBNAME);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, USER, PASS);
    }

    public List<Dog> readDogs() throws SQLException {
        List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "SELECT * from dogs";
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (result.next()) {
            int id = result.getInt("id");
            String name = result.getString("name");
            String ownerName = result.getString("owner_name");
            int age = result.getInt("age ");
            Dog dog = new Dog(id, name , ownerName , age);
            dogs.add(dog);
        }
        return books;
    }

    public boolean deleteDog(Dog selected) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "DELETE from dogs WHERE id = ? ";
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setInt(1, selected.getId());
        return stmt.executeUpdate() == 1; 
    }
}
```

Connection to my database.

Comment: int age = result.getInt("age "); is probably causing issues when you execute the query and try to instantiate your Dog. Be careful with white spaces.